# Freez Component after redirection

Tags: angular, rxjs, state, angular-routing

Hello everyone I have a component with ag grid that is a field after loading some accounts and a sidebar I want when I navigate into another component by url and come back to the other component it doesn't reload.

I tried using local storage, but every time it passes by ngOnInit I want from the component to be loaded just the first time after the redirection and stays frozen and hold his current state.

Comment: When navigating to the same component, by default the `ngOnInit` will not run every time. I would suggest you to inject the `ActivatedRoute` to your component and subscribe on the params change.

You can a similar thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42835928/6442841 .
Also, some code would be useful to help you more.

Comment: but every time i switch between routes it triggered ngOninit and reload all the data and i have to pick a date , filter the accounts and then load them. i don't want to pass the data with the url i want from the component to stay freezed like when i do minimize to the browser

Comment: You don't need to pass any data, please read the relative thread.