# angular 2: Reload same component again when redirect on the same route

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I am using 'routerLink' to navigate my routes and it is working fine. But when I click again on the same button, I want that component will load again. But currently, it's not working in angular2.

> app.component.html

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a [routerLink]="['/events']" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">All Events</a></li>
            <li><a [routerLink]="['/events/new']" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">Create New</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want, When I click on 'All Events' tab, again and again, events component load every time.

How to achieve this scenario in angular2 ?

Comment: why you want to load same component again and again ?

Comment: please look at this post its similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47855240/angular-force-load-of-same-route?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 6):

> I want, When I click on 'All Events' tab, again and again, events component load every time.

This is `Not Possible` in angular2, reason is once you load any component that component is only reload once you navigate from another route to that route again.

> But you can reload forcefully

Basically there are two methods which are

- you can call `ngOnInit()` method again and again as per need, which is not a recommended way
- you   can call one commonn method from `ngOnInit()` and later as per need call that function again like this

  ```
  ngOnInit(){
      this.callingFunction();
  }

  forLaterUse(){
      this.callingFunction(); 
  }
  ```

> Another way is if you want to load same component on param change you can use this in constructor

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    console.log(params); 
    this.callingFunction();
    // this will be called every time route changes
    // so you can perform your functionality here

});
```

Comment: this is different question just strikes now, Is there any chance of restricting to load component on navigating from other route to same route ?.

Answer (score 5):

This github link below has the right solution 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13831

Put the below code in the constructor of the component which you want to load

```
this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
  return false;
};

this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
  if (evt instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    this.router.navigated = false;
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

See here:  [How to reload the current route with the angular 2 router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40983055/how-to-reload-the-current-route-with-the-angular-2-router)

To summarize - its not a function that is built into the router. It sounds like the best option is using a service that will refresh or re-fetch any relevant data, and if anything changes, Angular will automatically update the view.

If someone says something is not possible in Angular, that is almost always not true. Its just not possible using currently existing solutions.  ;-)

Comment: `If someone says something is not possible in Angular, that is almost always not true` dude but according to scenario its not possible in angular's way.

Comment: Yes i was just being cheeky. :-p. You did provide solutions after all