# How to Refresh a Component in Angular

Tags: angular, routes, components, refresh

I am working on an Angular project. I'm struggling with refresh action in a component. 
I would like to refresh the router's components on button click.
I have refresh button when I click on it the component/router need to be refresh.
I tried `window.location.reload()` and `location.reload()` these two are not suitable for my need. Please help if anyone aware of it.

Comment: Can you share your code in this question ? what you are tried.

Comment: it's a complex code, it has N number of  line of code, difficult to share

Comment: @Saurabh, normally it's not necesary reload a component. You can have a function (e.g. call "restart") and call the function in your button Refresh. If you need subscribe to change path, or another service, use the function ngOnInit -your component must extends OnInit-, not the constructor

Comment: This is what I did with Angular 9 https://stackoverflow.com/a/60909777/1072395

Answer (score 175, accepted):

After some research and modifying my code as below, the script worked for me. I just added the condition:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/RefreshComponent', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
    this.router.navigate(['Your actualComponent']);
});
```

Comment: I'm using this in an injectable service. I replaced `"your actualComponent"` with a variable. The variable is set is set to [`this.location.path()`](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#path) before the call to `navigateByUrl`. That way, no need to pass any parameters from calling component or duplicate/pass around routes.

Comment: can you please explain what is 'RefrshComponent' and 'Your actualComponent'?

Comment: Most everyone will be fine using `'/'` where `/RefrshComponent` is, and for `[Your actualComponent"]` you would just pass the url (and/or params) that you would like to reload such as `this.router.navigate(["/items"])`. This hack essentially redirects to the top URL, and then very quickly back to the intended URL which is unnoticeable to most users and appears to be the most elegant hack to achieve this simply.

Comment: I agree this should definitely work... but it fails in my app (Angular 6). If I use `'/'` as my dummy route it goes (via `redirectTo`) to where my app-routing.module.ts redirects to on a path of `''` (empty string) and stops, not proceeding to the completion route in the `navigate()` call. If I use a non-existent string (e.g. `/foo`) as my dummy route, it goes (via `redirectTo`) to where my app-routing.module.ts redirects for `**` (everything else) and again stops, not going to the real route. Curiously, the URL bar DOES change to the real route. Any thoughts on what is different here?

Comment: this can cause an infinite redirection loop if not used carefully

Comment: It works like a charm. I just tested in Angular 8. Why this may create infinite redirection loop @TomasKatz?

Comment: How do you use this without a loop? You can only call this manually if you know if it is the first load or not...

Comment: What about 'this' keyword when this.router.navigate(['Your actualComponent']).then... is finished ? What context is used ?

Comment: Thanks! In my case, this helped me to reload the table with angular-datatable without the need to apply the rerender method that is explained in its documentation and the code is very dirty.

Comment: I have a header component, while navigating from login route to account route, can I reload just the header component?

Comment: This worked for me.  The only thing was that I had to show a white page during the transition.  I wish if angular had a cleaner way to do so.   But as an interim fix it is fine.

Answer (score 110):

Use the **this.ngOnInit();** to reload the same component instead reloading the entire page!!

```
DeleteEmployee(id:number)
  {
    this.employeeService.deleteEmployee(id)
    .subscribe( 
      (data) =>{
        console.log(data);

        this.ngOnInit();

      }),
      err => {
        console.log("Error");
      }   
  }
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: This is a better input than the selected answer but it lacks explanation. In my specific case I had to refresh a child component. In that case there are several way but the recommended are using a service or broadcasting an event from the parent to the child.

Comment: Agreed, this only works if you want to refresh the component from within the component - if you are dealing with child/external components this.ngOnInit() will not work

Comment: Even though it works for component, it doesn't reset form validators.

Comment: Works perfect, thank you. And regarding the explanation AFAIC, the code says it all.

Comment: ngOnInit is a lifecycle method called by angular. you shouldn't call it yourself. if there's some logic from ngOnInit that you want to execute again, just move it into a method and call that method.

Comment: it definitely work, just add this **this.ngOnInit();** and component will refresh without reload the page

Comment: I read everything many times, checked the answer twice, but still I have no idea how is this an answer to question "How to Refresh a Component". Neither ngOnInit has any logic that can affect render process, nor it can rerender a component. Sure you can do some magic in code of ngOnInit that will rerender the component, but by default there is no built in functionality for things like this in ngOnInit

Answer (score 31):

Adding this to code to the required component's constructor worked for me.

```
this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
  return false;
};

this.mySubscription = this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    // Trick the Router into believing it's last link wasn't previously loaded
    this.router.navigated = false;
  }
});
```

Make sure to `unsubscribe` from this *mySubscription* in `ngOnDestroy()`.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.mySubscription?.unsubscribe();
}
```

Refer to this thread for more details -  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13831

Answer (score 25):

Fortunately, if you are using Angular 5.1+, you do not need to implement a hack anymore as native support has been added. You just need to **set onSameUrlNavigation to 'reload'** in the RouterModule options :

```
@ngModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: ‘reload’})],
 exports: [RouterModule],
 })
```

More information can be found here: https://medium.com/engineering-on-the-incline/reloading-current-route-on-click-angular-5-1a1bfc740ab2

Comment: You can use `router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload'` property of injected Router, too.

Comment: Using angular 6, to me this made no difference, that is, component did not reload. The accepted answer works however.

Comment: Although not entirely clear in the docs, `onSameUrlNavigation` is intended to reinvoke Guards/Resolvers, and not to reload already routed components. See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21115 for more on this. This solution will work for larger more complex applications using Guards/Resolvers but will fail for simple examples.

Comment: yes, onSameUrlNavigation will fire the navigation events again, but this does not reload the component

Comment: yes! this solution is working. May be you could mention more detail in you answer.

Answer (score 18):

calling `ngOnInit()` does not work for my complicated component, I end up using this

```
reloadCurrentRoute() {
    let currentUrl = this.router.url;
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(() => {
        this.router.navigate([currentUrl]);
    });
}
```

Comment: Simple and efficient. All other answers did not yield desired behavior, especially when using a child component requiring a reload of the parent component too.

Answer (score 13):

this is little bit out of box and I dont know whether this helps you or not but have yo tried

`this.ngOnInit();`

its a function so whatever code you have in it will be recalled just like a refresh.

Answer (score 12):

One more way without explicit route:

```js
async reload(url: string): Promise<boolean> {
  await this.router.navigateByUrl('.', { skipLocationChange: true });
  return this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution. It worked for me with no side effects.

Comment: Actually it gives Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '.'  if you don't have the route in the application routes

Answer (score 10):

Just follow the below steps:

1. add `{onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'}` as below in your app-routing.modules.ts

> @NgModule({
> imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})],
> exports: [ RouterModule ]
> })

2. add `this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false` as below in you component ts file constructor:

> ```
> constructor(private router: Router) {
>       this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
>   }
> ```

3. Now click the button and call ajax server call, get the desired data from server and replace your global variable in TS file with new data.
4. call  `this.router.navigate([/sameRoute]);` in the last.
   replace sameRoute with your route url.
5. make sure to return false at the end in your refresh button's onClick method, otherwise it will lead to main routing page instead of same page reload. 
   These steps will reload your page. :)

For more details:  https://medium.com/engineering-on-the-incline/reloading-current-route-on-click-angular-5-1a1bfc740ab2

I am using Angular 12.

Comment: This is the correct answer for me thanks god. You can change 4 with this.router.navigateByUrl(this.router.url);

Comment: Amazing! This is the only solution that worked for me! I'm using Angular 13

Comment: Adding ```this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;``` worked for me

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved via a hack, Navigate to some sample component and then navigate to the component that you want to reload.

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/SampleComponent', { skipLocationChange: true });
this.router.navigate(["yourLandingComponent"]);
```

Comment: SampleComponent means it should be an empty component or another component in my project?

Comment: it should be a dummy one, can be empty

Comment: Ok I will try this

Comment: if I give true I am getting an error message : [ts] Type 'true' has no properties in common with type 'NavigationExtras'

Comment: @SreehariBallampalli check the updated answer, you need to pass an object  { skipLocationChange: true }

Comment: your solution not working, and also i debugged the code, first it is going to this url - this.router.navigateByUrl('/SampleComponent', { skipLocationChange: true }); and then  it is going to this url -this.router.navigate(["yourLandingComponent"]);  here noting refreshing/reloading i am getting same issue, if you can provide me a better solution that may help me

Comment: NavigateByUrl was not doing any help in my case. It requires this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
      return false;
    };

Answer (score 3):

There are problems with some of the answers before:

1. one should not call lifecycle methods such as *ngOnInit()* directly.
2. re-navigating to some URL is a sub-optimal solution, especially if the component you are dynamically loading is only a small part of a big page

This worked for me (I don't know if it is recommendable or optimal)

1. In the component to be dynamically loaded, add a *public* reference to the *ChangeDetectorRef*.
2. I assume that the dynamically loaded data has some input data, ("*tags*" in the example), which is updated after the fact and is creating rendering problems.

```js
  @Input()
  tags: string[] = [];

  constructor(public changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef )
```

3. In the parent component doing the dynamic loading, after having created the child component dynamically and maybe set some data to it, call the created instance's *changeDetector.markForCheck()* as follows:

```js
  constructor(private vcrf: ViewContainerRef, private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver, private elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  public loadComponent(): void {

    const componentFactory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(TagsListComponent);
    const component = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);
    component.instance.tags = /* whatever data we want to pass */;
    component.instance.changeDetector.markForCheck();
    ...
```

*loadComponent()*  is a custom function that could be called, for example, once the parent page scrolls to some position in the parent component, indicating that the dynamic component should be shown.

Answer (score 2):

In my application i have component and all data is coming from API which i am calling in Component's constructor.
There is button by which i am updating my page data. on button click i have save data in back end and refresh data.
So to reload/refresh the component - as per my requirement - is only to refresh the data.
if this is also your requirement then use the same code written in  constructor of component.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the `routeReuseStrategy` from the angular Router:

```js
this._router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
      return false;
    };
```

Set the routerproperty "navigated" to false:

```js
this._router.navigated = false;
```

Then navigate to your component:

```js
this._router.navigate(['routeToYourComponent'])
```

After that reinstate the old/default routeReuseStrategy:

```js
this._router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function (future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
          return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
```

You can also make a service out of this:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RouterService {

  constructor(
    private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router
  ) { }

  reuseRoutes(reuse: boolean) {
    if (!reuse) {
      this._router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
        return false;
      };
    }
    if (reuse) {
      this._router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function (future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
      };
    }
  }

  async refreshPage(url?: string) {
    this._router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
      return false;
    };

    this._router.navigated = false;

    url ? await this._router.navigate([url]) : await this._router.navigate([], { relativeTo: this._activatedRoute });

    this._router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function (future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
      return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across this when looking for the same problem.
And I found there were too many solutions across stackoverflow with similar/tweaked answers.

I believe the answer can be different based on what you're trying to achieve:

1. Just reload some API on the current component (Similar to calling a simple `init()` function again)
2. Tell angular to re-create all components on the page (Services and data saved in stores remain as is)
3. Reload the guards, resolvers, etc. in Angular (Router related events)
4. Reload all assets on the page including HTML, CSS, etc. (Browser refresh)

---

Summarizing the solutions here for easier reference:

**Solution 1**: Just call `ngOnInit()`

```js
class MyComponent {
    ngOnInit() {...}

    reinitComponent() {
        this.ngOnInit();
    }
}
```

Notes:

- This does not refresh the entire state of the current component - for example variable set in the constructor will not be changed
- We should not be calling a angular lifecycle hook explicitly
- This just affects the current component (not all components in page)

*Alternate syntax*: Move this logic to a separate `init()` function and call it in both places

```js
class MyComponent {
    ngOnInit() {
        this.init();
    }

    init() { ... }

    reinitComponent() {
        this.init();
    }
}
```

---

**Solution 2A**: Route to another route and return back to current route

```js
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

class MyComponent {
    constructor(private route: ActivateRoute, private router: Router) {}

    refreshPage() {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
            this.router.navigate([], { relativeTo: this.route });
        });
}
```

Notes:

- Need to have a intermediate route that can be used
- Sometimes the intermediate route can cause
- Does not refresh the states of global root injected services (For example if you save currentLoggedInUser in a service)
- If the intermediate route has a HTML template, it will be shown to the user momentarily
- Using this you can control how many parent components angular will re-create (For example intermediate route can be `../..` to avoid recreating all components till the top)

**Solution 2B**: Use Angular `RouteReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute`

This requires 3 steps:
*Step 1*: When configuring router module, use `onSameUrlNavigation`

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
            onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
        })
    ]
}
export class MyRoutingModule {}
```

*Step 2*: Change the RouteReuse strategy in Angular so that it does not reuse the component based on a queryParams

```js
import { Injectable, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, BaseRouteReuseStrategy, RouteReuseStrategy, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
class CustomRouteReuseStrategy extends BaseRouteReuseStrategy {
    shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        return super.shouldReuseRoute(future, curr) && future.queryParams._refreshing !== 'true';
    }
}

@NgModule({
    providers: [
        {
            provide: RouteReuseStrategy,
            useClass: CustomRouteReuseStrategy,
        },
    ],
    imports: [ // This is from Step 1
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
            onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
        })
    ]
}
export class MyRoutingModule {}
```

*Step 3*: And finally use it in a component

```js
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
class MyComponent {
    constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

    refreshPage() {
        router.navigate([], {
            relativeTo: route,
            queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
            queryParams: { _refreshing: true },
            skipLocationChange: true,
        });
    }
```

Notes:

- This will re-create all components on this page

---

**Solution 3**: Use angular configs to always run router events on same url

When configuring router module, use `onSameUrlNavigation`

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
            onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
        })
    ]
}
export class MyRoutingModule {}
```

Notes:

- This will just call guards/resolvers
- The component for the route will remain the same and angular will not re-create the components on the page

---

**Solution 4**: Tell the browser to refresh the page using Browser APIs

```js
class MyComponent {
    refreshBrowserTab() {
        window.location.reload();
    }
```

Notes:

- Reloads the entire page, including all assets like CSS, HTML, JS, images, fonts, etc.

*Alternate syntax*: Uses Angular's location which can be altered with DI to mock it during tests

```js
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

class MyComponent {
    constructor(private location: Location) {}

    refreshBrowserTab() {
        this.location.reload();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I know, this is an old question, but from my point of view, still a valid one. I came across the same issue, and none of the previous solutions were satisfying to me.
The best solution, from my point of view, was this one:

```js
this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
```

unfortunately, this is deprecated: https://angular.io/api/router/Router

After a while of research, I found a practical solution, which is suitable for all my needs and actually works with Angular 17.

### Step 1:

Open your app.config.ts and extend your appConfig:

```js
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes,
      withRouterConfig({onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'}),
    ),
    {
      provide: RouteReuseStrategy,
      useClass: AppRouterReuseStrategy,
    },
  ],
};
```

### Step 2:

Create a new file, called: app.router-reuse-strage.ts (or something else, dosn't matter) and paste the following content:

```js
export class AppRouterReuseStrategy extends BaseRouteReuseStrategy {
  override shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    window.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: 'instant'})
    return (future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig) && !future.data['reloadComponent'];
  }
}
```

### Step 3:

Now you can enable the force reload the component, just by extending your routes

```js
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('...').then(m => m.LandingRoutingModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'persons',
    loadChildren: () => import('...').then(m => m.PersonRoutingModule),
    data: {
      'reloadComponent': true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: NotFoundComponent,
  },
];
```

I hope this helps someone :-)

Comment: Thank you, you've saved me! I wasn't sure where exactly to apply `BaseRouteReuseStrategy`, but you've shown me the way

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why but I thought the route reuse strategy needed to go in the main app component as a provider for a standalone app since all the examples I found prior to this had it being added to the main ngModule.

Answer (score 1):

kdo

```
// reload page hack methode

push(uri: string) {
    this.location.replaceState(uri) // force replace and no show change
    await this.router.navigate([uri, { "refresh": (new Date).getTime() }]);
    this.location.replaceState(uri) // replace
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
constructor(private router:Router, private route:ActivatedRoute ) { 
}

onReload(){
 this.router.navigate(['/servers'],{relativeTo:this.route})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just do this : (for angular 9)

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';    
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document){ }

someMethode(){ this.document.location.reload(); }
```

Comment: Please read the OPs comment, refreshing the whole page is not an option for him, it defeats the purpose of having angular in the first place

Comment: The question ask for reload component only not whole page.

Answer (score 0):

html file

```
<a (click)= "getcoursedetails(obj.Id)" routerLinkActive="active" class="btn btn-danger">Read more...</a>
```

ts file

```
  getcoursedetails(id)
  { 
  this._route.navigateByUrl('/RefreshComponent', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
    this._route.navigate(["course",id]);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

`router.navigate['/path']` will only takes you to the specified path
use `router.navigateByUrl('/path')`
it reloads the whole page

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to reload specific routes (not all in the application), so adding the global setting `{onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'}` had no effect, while `this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false` in the component works but modifies the global settings of the router.

The solution was to save the original router configuration to a variable before changing it in the component's constructor as indicated @abhishek-singh by the first answer of the problem.

```js
private routeReuseStrategy:any;

  constructor(
    private router:Router
  ) {
    this.routeReuseStrategy = this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute;
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
  }
```

And when exiting the path, remap the original configuration using the OnDestroy hook.

```js
   public ngOnDestroy():void
   {
     this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = this.routeReuseStrategy;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: this.ngOnInit();

Answer (score 0):

```
private saveRouterStrategyReuseLogic: any;


ngOnInit() {
    // Save logic
    this.saveRouterStrategyReuseLogic = this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute;
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = (future, curr) => { return false; };
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = 
this.saveRouterStrategyReuseLogic;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Import ActivatedRoute and Router:

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
```

Then add them to your constructor:

```
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
  )
```

After that in the function that you want the reloading of the page to happen:

```
   reloadURL(): void {
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
    this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
    this.router.navigate(['./'], {
      relativeTo: this.route,
    });
  }
```

It will then reload the very component that you are on, simple as that.

Answer (score -2):

`reload () { this.ngOnInit(); }`

Answer (score -4):

**Other way to refresh (hard way) a page in angular 2 like this** 
**it's look like f5**

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private location: Location) {}

pageRefresh() {
   location.reload();
}
```

Comment: He said that reloading the whole page isn't suitable, this reloads the whole page, not just a single/multiple components.

Comment: I ended up using this, except the angular location service doesn't have a reload, so I used window.