# How to refresh one component (nav-bar) when button is clicked from another component?

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, angular6

I want to reload component after a button click from another component Angular 6.

Comment: add some of your codes which may help us understand your problem better.

Comment: use eventEmitter();  trigger eventEmitter() in one component and capture that in other component, trigger the refresh function(). :D

Comment: @AkhilAravind can you provide some sample code

Comment: @MariyamMohammedJalil,  i will try

Comment: related (not sure if it's a duplicate, since this question is about the navbar) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47813927/how-to-refresh-a-component-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

As @MariyamMohammedJalil said you can use an EventEmitter to trigger the update of your first component.

See following sample:

**first.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'first-component',
    template: '<div>{{label}}</label>
})
export class FirstComponent {

    @Input() update: EventEmitter<string>;

    label = 'First Component';

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.update) {
            // Subscribe to the event emitter to receive an update event
            this.update.subscribe((value: string) => {
                this.refresh(value);
            })
        }
    }

    refresh(value: string) {
        // Do your stuff here
        this.label = value;
    }

}
```

**second.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'second-component',
    template: '<button (click)="updateFirstCmp()">Update First Component</button>'
})
export class SecondComponent {

    @Input() update: EventEmitter<string>;

    constructor(){}

    updateFirstCmp() {
        // Emit an event to update your first component
        this.update.emit('Updated First Component');
    }

}
```

And for example you should add following to your `app.component.ts`:

```
updateEventEmitter: EventEmitter<string>;

constructor() {
    ...   
    this.updateEventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
}
```

And in your `app.component.html`:

```
<first-component [update]="updateEventEmitter"></first-component>

<second-component [update]="updateEventEmitter"
```

Another way do solve your problem can be to enter the `first.component` as input parameter to the `second.component` to call the refresh function directly without `EventEmitter`. See following sample:

**app.component.html**

```
<first-component #firstComponent></first-component>

<second-component [firstCmp]="firstComponent"></second-component>
```

**second.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'second-component',
    template: '<button (click)="updateFirstCmp()">Update First Component</button>'
})
export class SecondComponent {

    @Input() firstCmp: FirstComponent;

    constructor(){}

    updateFirstCmp() {
        // Update the first component directly
        this.firstCmp.refresh('Updated First Component');
    }

}
```

With this sample you don't need to subscribe to an update event, because you're not using an EventEmitter.