# How to Reload/Refresh the current page in Angular 6?

Tags: angular

> Reload or refresh the current page when a function isRefresh() is called.

Comment: try `window.location.reload`

Comment: It redirects to the homepage.I want to redirect it to the current page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Refresh a Component in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47813927/how-to-refresh-a-component-in-angular)

Comment: then you should use component refresh.

Comment: It won't redirect if you use path location strategy.

Comment: This actually gives me the cuurent page + the homepage together.it is redirected to the current page ,and if we  scroll down we see the homepage screen as well!

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal can u please explain refresh component.Dont have much idea about it.

Comment: Why would a reload redirect to homepage? you have got guards for the current route?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

This will do,

```
window.location.reload()
```

Comment: It doesn't meet the requirement. Redirects to homepage,not current page.

Comment: It's not supposed to redirect unless you are not doing routes and only using a single page actually. Can you provide a stackblitz demo?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the right way to usually approach things, but as an answer to your problem:

```
constructor(private router: Router){};
// Custom refresh code
reloadWindow() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(`/`).then(
            () => {this.router.navigateByUrl(this.router.url);});
}
```