# Refresh router on component.ts

Tags: angular, firebase

I want to reload my page route to refresh data stored in it. I can do this with putting `routerLink` on html but is there away that I can make this into a function in ts file? I have found `location.reload` and `location.href` but they refresh the whole page.

Code to retrieve message

```
receiveMessage(){
this.angularFiremessaging.messages.subscribe(
(payload) => {
console.log("new message received. ", payload);
this.currentMessage.next(payload);
});
}
```

My html

```
{{ (message | async)?.notification.title }}
{{ (message | async)?.notification.body}}
```

Comment: What kinda data you mean exactly you'd like to retrieve from router link, params?

Comment: Why to refresh all the page and not update the specific data?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid. I don't want to refresh the whole page. I just want my router to be reloaded so my html element can be updated.

Comment: @WebDeveloper What I'm trying to do is reload a route. For example, clicking on the home option of a menu when you are already viewing the homepage would refresh the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean params, you could use the `ActivatedRoute` for this purpose

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute)

ngOnInit() {
   this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      //will be fired on every param change in the url
      console.log('here are your params: ', params);
   });
}
```

Comment: Some sort like that. I'm working on a firebase push notification and I want my notify to be displayed in foreground automatically everytime I push it. The problem is that I have to reload my router for they to show up. I'm very appreciate your help but this does not solve my problem.

Comment: Okay, It's much better to share some code to define where the problem exactly is, would you ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/RefreshComponent', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
    this.router.navigate(['Your actualComponent']);
});
```

Reference: [How to Refresh a Component in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47813927/how-to-refresh-a-component-in-angular)

Comment: Excuse me sir. Can you explain to me what is RefreshComponent? You just made up, put some randomly component in there?

Comment: "This can be achieved via a hack, Navigate to some sample component and then navigate to the component that you want to reload."

Comment: Thank you. One more question sir. I don't know what is this.router is either. It's something you implement from import a service? Like ActiveRouter or Router?

Comment: Yes you need to import router from angular constructor(private router:Router ) { 
}