# Angular - Navigate to current same URL with component reload not the whole page

Tags: angular, routes

I am using Angular 5 library, I want to navigate to the current URL with reload (refresh) the whole component, not the page, I have read about navigation to current URL in Angular document.

And that it is what I need:

```
 /**
 * Define what the router should do if it receives a navigation request to the current URL.
 * By default, the router will ignore this navigation. However, this prevents features such
 * as a "refresh" button. Use this option to configure the behavior when navigating to the
 * current URL. Default is 'ignore'.
 */
onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' | 'ignore';
```

Now, I have tried to set the `onSameUrlNavigation` property to `reload` and then navigate to the same URL, but nothing happend, like this:

```
this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
this.router.navigate(['view'], { queryParams: { QueryUUID: selectedId } });
```

Anyone who has used this before can help?

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happened?  Did it not navigate to the route in the address bar?  Did it navigate to the default route?  Were there any errors on reload?

Comment: @Brad, just the parameter value changed, nothing else .

Comment: So what's not working?  Your question is not very clear on what is actually wrong.

Comment: after change the property and navigate, the page must reload(refresh) with new parameters, not just change the parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found this workaround method since the `onSameUrlNavigation` property in Angular 5.1 is not what I need.

I just need to override `shouldReuseRoute`, so added an exception for the component route that I want to refresh, if the current and future route are equal `view`.

> And also I can navigate to other routes without problems, even for navigate from Angular Material `sidenav`.

```
this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function (future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
  if (future.url.toString() === 'view' && curr.url.toString() === future.url.toString()) {
    return false;
  }
  return (future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig);
};
```

---

**Update:**

For those they want to use the new `onSameUrlNavigation` property in Angular 5.1 you can refer to this blog:

https://medium.com/engineering-on-the-incline/reloading-current-route-on-click-angular-5-1a1bfc740ab2

---

**Update:**

It is better to create a custom `RouteReuseStrategy` that override the default behavior, here it is how I do that:

```
export class AppRouteReuseStrategy implements BaseRouteReuseStrategy {

  // all other methods will be the same as the default

  /*
  * Determines if a route should be reused.
  * This strategy returns `true` when the future route config and current route config are identical.
  * 
  * but we want to refresh the route if the data.refreshComponent is true in the route definition
  * */
  shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    // so we need to check if it is true. if not, we return the default behavior
    return future.data.refreshComponent ? false : future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
  }
}
```

Then will add this as a `provider` in the `AppModule`:

```
{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: AppRouteReuseStrategy }
```

And the last thing to do is to mark which component you want to refresh in case of navigate to the same route, like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'view',
    component: ViewComponent,
    data: { refreshComponent: true },
  }
]
```

Comment: To the best of my understanding per https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21115 the router is a singleton so you're setting this setting application-wide even if it's just set in one component

Comment: Yes, you have to put it in a shared place, but remember I just override the setting in one case when the route is `view` else the base behavior will be processed.

Answer (score 11):

If I understand you correctly, this is how I do it:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
        params => {
            const id = +params['id'];
            this.getMovie(id);
        }
    );
}
```

Or to watch query parameters:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(param => {
        this.pageTitle = 'Movie List';
        this.getMovies();
    });
}
```

In the ngOnInit, I watch for changes to the parameters. When the parameters change, I re-retrieve the data.

Since the data is all bound, the page "refreshes" with the newly retrieved data.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have tried the same idea but with no success, because all service and charts I need to change its initial data already have been created, By creating a method that call the code inside `ngOnInit` but not worked, I need to reload the page with the new parameters.

Comment: As far as I know ... the above technique is how its normally done. There are no other features I know of to "reload" the page. Maybe if you could provide a plunkr or stackblitz demonstrating the issue, we could provide more assistance.

Comment: I am reading this blog, https://medium.com/engineering-on-the-incline/reloading-current-route-on-click-angular-5-1a1bfc740ab2, it is have what I want but still there is minor problem.

Comment: You may get a more valid answer then posting a question to his blog. Since this is a (very little publicized) new feature, there are probably not many of us here familiar with it.

Comment: Yeah, it is still new feature and not worked perfectly with me, Anyway, your answer is useful in some cases, and I have figured out a solution for now, Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is the right answer. Don't waste your time on onSameUrlNavigation

Answer (score 2):

In route module: 
add below in each route declaration

```
runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
```

and

```
@ngModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: ‘reload’})],
 exports: [RouterModule],
 })
```

for e.g `category/:id`

and this below part will be under Component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.activeRoute.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {
        // do something with the query params
    });
        this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(routeParams => {
        this.loadUserDetail(routeParams.id);
    });
}
```

for each route change say for e.g `category/11` and `category/12` it will call `loadUserDetail` function everytime.

So without refreshing page you will fetch data from server and update dom for same route with different roureParams.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of rel-loading the entire page, the normal `<a href="/">Reload Page</a>` tag works just fine for me. I tried using the "onSameUrlNavigation" function, but it was not reloading the entire page the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the angular router events for this purpose.

```
import { takeUntil, filter } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from "@angular/router";

this.router.events.pipe(
      filter((event): event is NavigationEnd => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll),
).subscribe(() => {
      this.cache = {};
      this.cachedRows = [];
      this.getRollingJobs(this.page);
});
```