# Angular 2 using routerLinkActive with path based arguments in URL

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

My app has 2 routes, a dashboard and a details page with an ID as a part of the url.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'documents/:documentUUID', component: DocumentDetailComponent },
])
```

For my nav bar, I have 2 links, `Dashboard` and `Training`. When I'm on the details page, (eg. /documents/01e328b8-822d-46d8-8229-78f4afb2e372/), the `Training` link should be highlighted. However, clicking on `Training` should never do anything.

This is what I have currently, this highlights the `Training` link correctly based on the URL. However clicking on `Training` triggers a `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'documents'` error in the console.

```
<nav>
    <a routerLink="/" [routerLinkActive]="'is-current'" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Dashboard</a>
    <a routerLink="/documents/" [routerLinkActive]="'is-current'" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: false}">Training</a>
</nav>
```

How can I achieve what I want to do without adding a href/routerLink to the `Training` Link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up getting the current url from `router.url` and using `[ngClass]` instead of `[routerLinkActive]`. Not my ideal solution but it works and and might make more sense.

```
<a [ngClass]="{'is-current': router.url.startsWith('/documents/')}">Training</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in the second link you have not passed and document id so it may be throwing an error of it.

Configure for the same url navigation to ignore.

[Angular - Navigate to current same URL with component reload not the whole page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48633674/angular-navigate-to-current-same-url-with-component-reload-not-the-whole-page)

Check the above link