# How to navigate to pages that only differ by url param?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a child component that can be reached from the parent with

```
 this.router.navigate(['./pathtochild/0'],{ relativeTo:
 this.activatedRoute });
```

this child has then links to siblings of the form /pathtochild/1, /pathtochild/2, etc.

Because these children only differ in the param number, it seems that

```
 this.router.navigate(['./pathtochild/1'],{ relativeTo: this.activatedRoute });
```

will not re-render the child view when only the param changes (but not the main path).

How can I navigate from one child to one of its siblings?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48280010/965834).

Answer (score 0):

You need to move up a level and then route to another child id. Should look like this:

```js
this.router.navigate(['../1'], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute });
```