# Angular 2 - How do I get router.navigate to cause canDeactivate to fire

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

When I call **router.navigate** with the same URI as the page that I am on, I do not see my canDeactivate service being called.

How do I force canDeactivate to fire even when the URI doesnt change for **router.navigate**?

It works when the router is navigating to a different URI.

Comment: You may find ideas in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40983055/1009922).

Comment: The link has a solution for Angular 5 which looks promising!