# Angular not reload if route to same param

Tags: angular

I want to reload a page `article/:id` every time a button is clicked, Angular is able to reload the page whenever the `:id` changed, but if route to same `:id`, then it ignores the changes.

```
export class DocumentComponent {
    constructor(
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.routeSubscription = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.reloadPage(+params['id']);
        });
    }

    clickReload(id: number) {
        this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
        this.router.navigate(['article', id]);
    }
}
```

When the params changed, the observable `params` will be triggered, and the `reloadPage()` is executed. However, when I try to reload the same `params`, Angular ignore it, how can I **reload** the same `param`?

```
article/123 --> article/456 [ok]
article/111 --> article/222 [ok]
article/666 --> article/666 [not ok, how?]
```

I try to use the `onSameUrlNavigation`, but it is not working... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why exactly do you want it to reload BTW? `activatedRoute.params` is a BehaviorSubject which only pushes a new value when it has changed. Since there's no change in the `id` it won't trigger a change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reload the current route with the angular 2 router](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40983055/9775003)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reload the current route with the angular 2 router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40983055/how-to-reload-the-current-route-with-the-angular-2-router)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the id if it is same then just reload the page. You can do like it:

```
clickReload(id: number) {
    if(id == this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id) {
        window.location.reload();    //if id is same then just reload the page
    } else {
        this.router.navigate(['article', id]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just add as below and remove the validation.. just the navigation is enough.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
    enableTracing: false
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

example :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mlc-onsameurlnavigation-activatedroute?file=app%2Fapp-routing.module.ts