# Angular 12: navigate and reload page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, navigation, reload

I have angular application in which I need to reload page after navigation. I have applied [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569884/angular-router-navigate-then-reload) solution but `window.location.reload();` does not work on production. So I have added `useHash: true` in `app-routing.module.ts` file. But that also giving me problems while applying SSR in application. So I need alternate way for below code:

```
this.router.navigate(['path/to'])
  .then(() => {
    window.location.reload();
  });
```

I have tried by applying `window.location.href = window.location.href` , `window.location.href = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/path/to';` instead of `window.location.reload();` but it does not reload the page as expected.

Is there any other way to achieve reloading after navigating in angular 12? Please help and guide.

**Edit :**
**Why reload:**
In application, after login of user, notifications are shown in header. That does not show data if page not reloaded.

Comment: Why do you need a reload?

Comment: It looks like you want an anchor tag behavior written in JavaScript. Am I right?

Comment: I think you are solving the wrong problem. If you want to refresh your login notifcations why not use a subscription or state solution like redux to update state from any placve?

Comment: @MaartenDev pls check Edit in question, for your question

Comment: @MaartenDev I am beginner to angular, not aware of solution you are suggesting. could you please give some example of your solution for angular? pls guide.

Comment: You could look into "Sharing data between angular components", you could checkout: https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Answer (score 1):

You could try to redirect to root and then redirect to your final destination:

```
this.router.navigate(['/'])
  .then(() => {
    this.router.navigate(['path/to'])
  });
```

Comment: tried above code also. not reloads page :(

Comment: did you try without the `useHash`?

Comment: removed `useHash` and tried above code still not reloading.