# Problems with onSameUrlNavigation

Tags: angular

In spite of putting {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'} in imports when I do reload in the same url, the page doesn't do nothing.

I don't know if the problem is caused by lazy load modules.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", pathMatch: "full", redirectTo: 'home' },
  { path: "home", loadChildren: () => import('./modules/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule) },
  { path: 'auth', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule) },
  { path: 'panel', canActivateChild: [authGuard], loadChildren: () => import('./modules/panel/panel.module').then(m => m.PanelModule) },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the use of onSameUrlNavigation property in Angular( versions greater than 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54062232/what-is-the-use-of-onsameurlnavigation-property-in-angular-versions-greater-tha)