# Angular routing- trying to refresh the same route does not work when it is the default path of the app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

I need to reload the current route.
I read many posts and the solution below works for me when I am reloading routes that are not defined as the default route of the app-

```
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(() =>
        this.router.navigate([XXXX])
    );
```

But for the default route this does not work for some reason, any ideas why?

My app-routing.module (output is my default route, and it is by lazy loading).

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'loginError',
        component: LoginErrorComponent
    },
    { path: 'settings',
        loadChildren: './settings/settings.module#SettingsModule',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    },
    { path: 'output',
        loadChildren: './researcher-output-list-standalone/researcher-output-list-standalone.module#ResearcherOutputListStandaloneModule',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    },
    { path: '',
        redirectTo: 'output',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    },
    { path: '**',
        redirectTo: 'output',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    },
];
```

Comment: if you are trying to reload  the page use `location.reload(true);` instead

Comment: I prefer not to reload the entire app, thanks!

Comment: may be this article will come handy : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40983055/how-to-reload-the-current-route-with-the-angular-2-router