# angular routerLink and click

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular6

I have my Angular 5 project. 
After login, the router is running, but the router does not work when I refresh the page.

I have not tried this as a solution but it did not work. 
I would appreciate if you help.

Link:

1-> https://medium.com/engineering-on-the-incline/reloading-current-route-on-click-angular-5-1a1bfc740ab2

2-> [How to reload the current route with the angular 2 router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40983055/how-to-reload-the-current-route-with-the-angular-2-router)

Code:

```
            <li>
                <a routerLink="/profile">
                    <i class="fi flaticon-user"></i>
                    profile
                </a>
            </li>
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Please specify what is your desired and current outcome.

Comment: thank you for answer. The router is running when the dom is first loaded. but does not reaction when I refresh the page.

Comment: Can you please create a Minimal Working Sample StackBlitz, replicating this issue? That would really help understand what's wrong and what your issue actually is.

Comment: This code works in mac book. however, it does not work in Ipad.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 <li>
               <a [routerLink]="['/profile']">
                    <i class="fi flaticon-user"></i>
                    profile
                </a>
            </li>
```

Comment: thank you for answer. but it did not work. The router is running when the dom is first loaded. but does not reaction when I refresh the page.

Comment: This code works in mac book. however, it does not work in Ipad.