# Angular5 Refresh only data, not whole application

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5

I have an app in Angular5 and NodeJS and now, when I click F5 on any of my pages, it tooks a loooong time to refresh and sometimes it don't show data. I think it reloads my whole application. There is any way to do "only data refresh" or something like that, so my whole app wouldn't be refreshed every single time I press F5?

Answer (score 0):

Intercepting **expected** browser behavior is a bad idea from UX perspective. What should happen if your application crashed or ended up in a state where I cannot go back to previous state? How should I "update" (read: pull the new code) your application? What if I  want to discard current state? Personally I'm pretty pissed at websites that change *any* browser behavior.

You might be interested in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event though.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can add "keydown" event listener to window:

```
if (event.keyCode === 116) {
      //retrieve data from server
      event.preventDefault();
}
```

This will stop page refresh on "F5" and perform your custom functionality.
But for user it might be strange that "F5" doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Maybe you can add routing functionality to reload routed component: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40983055/7885651

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys for all of your support!
I've done it using HostListener:

```
  @HostListener('document:keydown.F5', ['$event'])
  keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.getData();
  }
```

Now when somebody clicks F5 on page, it just reloads data (getData function, which gets fresh data from database).

BTW I know that disabling any of browser features is a bad way, but in this special scenario i just need this to work as I want.

Comment: What if I'm using the mouse or swipe to refresh?