# Re-initializing a component or forcing it to run ngOnInit() again in Angular

Tags: angular, ngoninit

I've got a table component in Angular that gets given different data depending on what the user has asked for and then populates a table. The table has gotten relatively complex and I need the entire component to essentially refresh when the user asks for something different. Is there a way to force the component to re-initialize when the user changes there selection on the parent component? Or maybe kill the component so that it has to re-load? I'm relatively new to Angular so I'm still trying to learn how the component life cycle works, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40983055/how-to-reload-the-current-route-with-the-angular-2-router) will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a utility function in your component, just make sure all the data required by your new state is ready.

```
redirect(uri:string){
   this.router.navigateByUrl('/', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(()=>
   this.router.navigate([uri]));
}
```

then use it like this

`this.redirect('//place your uri here');`

this function will redirect to a dummy route and quickly return to the destination route without the user realizing it.

Approach 2:
You can subscribe to router's navigation event.

```
 this.navigationSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe((e) => {
      // If it is a NavigationEnd event re-initialize the component
      if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            // implement your refresh logic here 
          }
        }
      }
    });
```