# Angular re-run ngOnInit when coming back to an initialized page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-router

When comming back to an initialized page it doesn't run ngOnInit. For example `/user/profile` shows username, I go on `/user/settings` change username, and came back to `/user/profile`. Username on `/user/profile` didn't change because ngOnInit wasn't called.

So what I want is to re-init page which has been already initialized.
This is `router.service.ts` which is used for navigation:

```
export class RouterService {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
  ) {
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
    this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = "reload";
  };


  async go(path: string[], options: NavigationExtras = {}) {
    this.router.navigate(path, { ...options });
  }
}
```

If I add `replaceUrl: true` to the function options it works, initted page re-inits, **but** the url is not being saved to the browser history and browser back button doesn't work (it redirects to the beggining of the app).

This is `app.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        ...
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

This is `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules, onSameUrlNavigation: "reload" }),
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Those are the routes:

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: "user/profile",
        loadChildren: () => import("./user/profile/profile.module").then(m => m.ProfilePageModule),
        canActivate: [LoggedGuard],
    },
    {
        path: 'user/settings',
        loadChildren: () => import('./user/settings/settings.module').then(m => m.SettingsPageModule),
        canActivate: [LoggedGuard],
    },
```

Comment: Those are **not** solutions: [navigating to '/' and then to actual url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65401966/re-initializing-a-component-or-forcing-it-to-run-ngoninit-again-in-angular), or using `window.location.reload()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ngOnInit()
```

The above method executes when the page/component is created. Probably executes when the page is added for first time in routing.This is angular component lifecycle event.

```
ionViewDidEnter()
```

This method is executed when we everytime enter the page or component.This is ionic page lifecycle event. So use **ionViewDidEnter()**

Comment: I feel terrible for only knowing about this after my 2nd Ionic App development. Used to apply all the public / event emitters / observables all over my application

Answer (score 0):

Lifecycle hooks aren't intended to be called manually. That said, in the main components which you want to re-run the routines, you can subscribe to router events and call whatever functions you wish when the route matches whatever value you wish it to for the given page.

Answer (score 0):

With this method in ionic you are destroying page stacks. You don't need to re-init a page, you can simply use ionic lifecycle hooks instead of angular's. `ionViewWillEnter` instead of `ngOnInit`, which is called whenever the page is opened, not when initiated.