# Force route transition to same route with different param in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In angular 1 with UI Router when I go to the same route but different param. Angular will reload the view. But in Angular 2 it doesn't. It just updates the data. But I need the user to feel like the page is transitioning to a different page.

What I have already tried is forcing angular 2 to route to a dummy route/component and then back to the designated route. I am using angular animations when transition from a route to a different a route. So this method has a bit of a delay and looks weird.

```
{path: "product/:id" }

routerLink="/product/30"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is very helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38129910/9027171

1 - You should add ActivatedRoute

```
import {Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
```

2 - and in Constructor

constructor(private activatedroute: ActivatedRoute,...

3 - and on ngOnInit() :

```
this.activatedroute.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params, params['rowid']);
      this.id = params['rowid']
        }
    });
```

After Subscribing your params will changed after navigation
NB : params['here_put_your_param_name']

Thank you :)