# this.navigate.url not working in promise

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to refresh a page (through this.navigate.url) when a promise is executed but I can't seem to make it work.

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

constructor(public router: Router) {
}

myPromise('/api/users').then((response) => {
    return response.json();
}).then(function (response) {
    this.router.navigate.url([url]);
});
```

I even tried window.location.reload and it doesn't work either.

Comment: What is `this` here? What does `this.navigate` do? Where does `url` come from? What does the console show?

Comment: Do you want to navigate inside your app with the help of the Angular router och to an external site?
If external, try `window.location.replace("http://something.com");`

Comment: @torazaburo I edited my question to elaborate further. router is an instance of Router class, url is current page URL. What I want is to refresh my current page after a promise is executed.

Comment: @FredrikLundin I want to refresh my page once a promise is successfully executed.

Comment: @torazaburo is there a refer to correct this answer for typescript/angular? Like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigating to the same route not refreshing the component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127308/navigating-to-the-same-route-not-refreshing-the-component)

Comment: I went through that particular question before creating mine. My URL isn't changing and nor do I want it to. I just need to perform a page reload after my promise is executed.

Answer (score 2):

```
constructor(private zone:NgZone) {}

this.zone.run(() => this.router.navigate(['main']));



//import NgZone from angular core, use zone.run inside the promise
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Some explanation would greatly improve the quality of the answer and help other users who may encounter similar problems in the future
Please take some time to read the help page https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

## Angular 6.0 Router link is always disabled in child component.

Router link is always disabled in child component, if our navigation code is inside promise. To solve this issue we can use NgZone inside promise.

Let me show you the file contents:

> login.component.ts

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core'; //import ngZone from angular core

constructor(private zone:NgZone) {}

authorize(): Promise<any> {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let promise = this.auth2.signIn();
  promise.then(() => {
    let self = this;
    let profile = this.auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
    this.authenticationService.login(profile);
    this.zone.run(() => this.router.navigate(['/contacts']));
  });
});
}
```