# Does router in angular 4 holds only one state and during navigation?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two states A and B.I navigated from state A to state B.When i navigating back to the state A from state B the state A is loading again in angular.Does the State A destroyed while navigating from state A to state B?If State A destroyed,then how to prevent the state A loading again in back navigation

Comment: please look into this link -  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280471/how-to-implement-routereusestrategy-shoulddetach-for-specific-routes-in-angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280471/how-to-implement-routereusestrategy-shoulddetach-for-specific-routes-in-angular)

Comment: Please have a look at this.This worked for my requirement.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44875644/custom-routereusestrategy-for-angulars-child-module/44876414#44876414

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Angular holds only 1 state at a time. there are multiple ways to save state, having a service that holds private variables with getters and setters, saving it in localStorage/sessionStorage, query strings, etc... each of these has their own pros and cons, i would research a bit more about it on angular.io in the router section.

There are few classes that a component can "implement" for example OnInit and OnDestroy, then you would have those functions in the code so you would load/save state on each load/leave.
Example:

```
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(){}
  onDestroy(){
    //save logic goes here
  }
  onInit() {
    //load logic goes here
  }
}
```

Of course, you can load the state in constructor as well, but i find onInit to be better performance wise. But feel free to correct me.